# Python Request Authorization

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, web-scraping

I need to pull some of my information of a web site for tax purposes, and unfortunately, the "export" features don't give me all the information I need.  The information does exist on the web site, as a single field in each of over 250 web pages.  I can click on each one and save them all and process them with a script, but I'd rather learn something instead.

The `request` package bills itself as being godsend for this, though I'm not wedded to it.  The problem is that I have to log into my web site.  `request`'s documentation includes [this link on authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/), documenting various forms of authentication, but contains no information on how to tell which form of authentication my web site actually uses.  I assume that a cookie of some sort is put on my computer when I log into the web site, and in theory, I could find that on my hard drive and send it along with my requests, but I have next to no experience with cookies and/or authorization and wouldn't know what to send.

If I can make a batch of requests to a list of urls, all on the same site, and download just the html, I can process it and build a report.

In your reply, if there are any links to general knowledge about how http authentication and cookies work together, I'd be happy to read that as well.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: [request *does* support cookies as well](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

*I'm using `BasicAuth` as it is the most common form of Auth; you can change it to any other form by looking at the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)*

Using the below as a "base code", you can create a `list` or `dict` of the `urls` to be visited and loop over them. The above code will also save you the trouble from having to "locate the cookies on the hard disk and load them".

> edit: after looking at OP's comments:

```
import requests

login_url = "https://www.wyzant.com/sso/login"    # this is the login for's action url, extracted it from the source code

payload = {
    "Username" : "<username>",
    "Password" : "<password>"
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    cookies = r.cookies
    r = s.get(url, cookies=cookies)    # do whatever
```

I've tried the exact code above, works perfectly, and I'm able to login and access the Student Dashboard.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that's the same link I posted.  The problem is that I don't know the login_url, and I don't even know if BasicAuth is being used.  When I click on the "login" button, it hands off to some javascript that I can't find to study.  For all I know, that javascript makes several http requests on my behalf, and then some magic happens, and I get my page.  Which of those http urls is the one I want?  So: given an arbitrary web site, what would be a basic workflow for determining what flavor of authentication it uses, and how to log in and access pages from my own scripts?

Comment: what's the base url?

Comment: wyzant.com.  I tried answering my own question and following this tutorial: https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/ -- I get about as far as the csrf token (wyzant doesn't have one) and get stuck.  It says, understandably, "Keep in mind that this is the specific case for this site. While this login form is simple, other sites might require us to check the request log of the browser and find the relevant keys and values that we should use for the login step."  I've got the network tab of Chrome's developer tools up for the request log, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: looks like their login_url is `wyzant.com` itself. Also, they seem to be using `XHR` (XmlHttpRequest) in order to authenticate. Hence, using basic auth should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I'l take a look at it after the holiday festivities tonight.  How did you learn that information?

Comment: I try `curl -u username:password https://www.wyzant.com` and I get the login page as html.  I tried a few other urls and got similar results.

Comment: @EdKrohne I've edited and fixed it now. Works perfectly on my machine. If it works then do accept and upvote it. cheers.

Comment: Works great as long as you do `s.get` instead of `requests.get`.  Also, when I successfully log in, whether I use `s.get` or `requests.get`, I get an empty cookie jar when I `print(cookies)`, i.e., `<RequestsCookieJar[]>` is printed to the screen.  When I _fail_ to log in, the cookie jar is nonempty.  Not sure why.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Ah, I edited your answer and accepted it, but the edit is waiting on a peer review.  I would have answered my own question, but since the question is on hold, I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted.  Thank you so much.